# Does anybody use Pancake? MathJax

Tags: discussion, mathjax

```
$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots a_1 \end{align*}$$
```

#### Delete a_1 in the above, then that could be shown well.

```
$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots \end{align*}$$
```

http://hypergroups.pancakeapps.com/Test/test.txt

Of course they can show well in Math.SE

$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots a_1 \end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots \end{align*}$$

---

The MathJax here and Pancake are not the same?

[image]

The latex codes aer in the post. You can create a .txt file and add the mathJax script codes which could be obtained by saving my webpage linked to get the ... codes, because I cannot put it here, Math.SE compile something about that.

---something wrong with the follwoing code, How can I keep a raw codes in Math.SE?

`<script type="text/x-mathjax-config;executed=true">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
  processEscapes: true
  },
TeX: {
            equationNumbers: {
                autoNumber: ["AMS"],
                useLabelIds: true
            }
        },
        "HTML-CSS": {
            linebreaks: {
                automatic: true
            },
            scale: 85
        },
        SVG: {
            linebreaks: {
                automatic: true
            }
        }
});
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Pancake.io_files/MathJax.js">
</script>`

Comment: Did you try to right-click the formula on Pancake? Also, I'm pretty sure that Pancake support questions are off-topic on meta.MSE.

Comment: @user90090 what do you mean? I donot know right-click, The right formulas seems show automatically

Comment: @user90090 see my picture, one is good, one is not

Comment: @HyperGroups: Why should the last `a_1` or `a1` *not* be shown? Given the source code, it seems to me that MathJax is correct and Pancake is not.

Comment: @robjohn The latex codes aer in the post. You can create a .txt file and add the mathJax script codes which could be obtained by saving my webpage linked to get the <script>...<script> codes, because I cannot put it here, Math.SE compile something about that.

Comment: What does this have to do with math.stackexchange?

Comment: @mrf People may store/link their papers/things/pdf in Pancake. and This is also about mathJax, MarkDown and latex and html?

Comment: No, this is about the running of math.stackexchange.

Comment: @mrf this may offer a possible bug math.stackexchange may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code from [that page](http://hypergroups.pancakeapps.com/Test/test.txt) is

```
<p>$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha <em>1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots a</em>1 \end{align*}$$</p>`

<p>$$\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\cdots+\alpha _n,a_2=\alpha _1\alpha _2+\alpha _1\alpha _3+\cdots+\alpha _{n-1}\alpha _n,\cdots \end{align*}$$</p>
```

My guess is that the `<em>...</em>` tags are preventing MathJax from processing the first paragraph.

It seems like a preprocessing step is changing the underscores in the latex source into italic text in the HTML.

Comment: Ah, I see, I The original file is .txt, interesting...I don't know why the first $$formulas become a html format add some tags such like <p> <em>...

Comment: I find a workaround, that is saving my original file as .html. The bad thing is then I cannot use MarkDown in the middle of HTML codes...

Comment: If the markdown processor does not understand enough to ignore the latex, then there may be an incompatibility. Sometimes altering the order of the MathJax and markdown processing can fix such incompatibilities, but that seems a fragile solution.

Comment: I found another method is to modify the tex code, you notify me that the <em> tag, then I delete the spaces, This is ok now.`\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n,a_2=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}\alpha_n,\cdots a_1\end{align*}`

Comment: Yes, the absence of spaces on either side of an underscore should prevent that from being handled as markdown.

Comment: How to copy with $x_\mu$ and $y_\mu$ properly?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Pancake is using the underscore to initiate italics (notice how everything between the first and last underscore is in italics and the underscores have been removed).  Since the Pancake processing is done before the MathJax processing, this means that Pancake has modified the math to remove those underscores and insert `<em>...</em>` tags.  That will prevent MathJax from processing the mathematics, since it doesn't process anything containing HTML tags.

In order to get this to work, you would need to be able to tell Pancake *not* to process underscores inside the math delimiters.  The best solution would be to modify Pancake to know about MathJax delimiters and not modify anything inside.  But you may also be able to work around that by using some sort of "verbatim" mode (that allows you to provide unmodified text).  In Markdown, that is handled by a back-tick, so `` `$...$` `` would allow you to enter mathematics unmodified.  But this may cause the math to be enclosed in `<code>` tags, and you might need to modify the MathJax configuration to remove `"code"` from the `skipTags` parameter in the `tex2jax` section of the configuration.

PS, I see @robjohn has identified the `<em>` problem already.

Comment: ha, possible, Pancake support markdown html and mathjax in one .txt file, may have some conflicts.

Comment: I find a workaround, that is saving my original file as .html. The bad thing is then I cannot use MarkDown in the middle of HTML codes...

Comment: I found another method is to modify the tex code, you notify me that the <em> tag, then I delete the spaces, This is ok now.`\begin{align*}a_1=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n,a_2=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\a‌​lpha_1\alpha_3+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}\alpha_n,\cdots a_1\end{align*}`

Comment: How to copy with $x_\mu$ and $y_\mu$ properly?